# Is there a ruling for giving and returning the Salam while eating?

Tags: food, greetings

What is the ruling, if any, of offering salaam to someone who is eating?
And also what is the ruling when being offered salaam while you yourself are eating?

Lately, we hear people saying that it is forbidden to say "Salam" while eating. Hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clear hadith or verse of the Quran which forbids you from saying salam to someone who is eating, or someone saying salam while they are eating.

For detailed scholarly view,you can consult: http://web.archive.org/web/20140825013058/http://islamqa.info:80/en/150591

Comment: maybe you could try answering some of [these](http://islam.stackexchange.com/unanswered) as time permits and as you feel are useful and worth answering..